# How to install WPN-XM server on different disk partition?

Tags: installation, server, wpn-xm

I tried installation of WPN-XM Server on different disk space - for instance, `D:/WPNXM Server` but I received an error message during server starting process.

Where is a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In general the installation on another disk shouldn't be a problem.

But here the problem is the space in the installation path!

Please change the installation folder from `D:\WPNXM Server` 
to `D:\WPNXM-Server` or simply `D:\server`.

(I've modified the installer to disallow spaces in the installation path to prevent this kind of errors. The changes will ship with the next release v0.8.7.)